# Arbitrary instance for TimeOfDay

Tags: haskell, time, quickcheck

Using QuickCheck, I'd like to create a series of pseudorandom [`TimeOfDay`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/time-1.9.3/docs/Data-Time-LocalTime.html#t:TimeOfDay) values.

It's easy to create a specific `TimeOfDay`:

```
now = TimeOfDay 17 35 22
```

Printing this with GHCi 8.6.5 yields:

> 17:35:22

I thought that the `Arbitrary` instance necessary for creating `TimeOfDay` values with QuickCheck would thus be:

```
instance Arbitrary TimeOfDay where
  arbitrary = do
    hour <- elements [0 .. 23]
    min  <- elements [0 .. 59]
    -- Going till 60 accounts for leap seconds
    sec  <- elements [0 .. 60]
    return $ TimeOfDay hour min sec
```

Although this typechecks, running the following line hangs GHCi and after a couple of seconds writes `Killed` to the console:

```
sample (arbitrary :: Gen TimeOfDay)
```

Where's the bug?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you found out, the `todSeconds` has as type [**`Pico`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Data-Fixed.html#t:Pico) which is a fixed-point number with a resolution of *10<sup>-12</sup>*, so that means that `[0 .. 60]` has *6×10<sup>13</sup>+1* values. This will easily take ~1000 seconds to iterate over the entire list.

That being said, you do not need to use `elements` here in the first place. We can use [**`choose :: Random a => (a, a) -> Gen a`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/QuickCheck-2.13.2/docs/Test-QuickCheck.html#v:choose) that will generate a random value within bounds (both bounds inclusive).

We can then define our `Arbitrary` as:

```
instance Arbitrary TimeOfDay where
    arbitrary = TimeOfDay
        <$> choose (0, 23)
        <*> choose (0, 59)
        <*> (fmap MkFixed (choose (0, 61*10^12-1)))
```

This then gives us:

```
Main> sample (arbitrary :: Gen TimeOfDay)
15:45:04.132804129488
11:06:12.447614162981
12:07:50.773642440667
04:40:47.966398431784
02:30:09.60931551059
00:51:46.564756092467
07:57:44.170698241052
02:45:57.743854623407
00:17:22.627238967351
13:03:57.364852826473
11:12:34.894890974241
```

If you do not want these picoseconds, we can do the multiplication in the `fmap`:

```
instance Arbitrary TimeOfDay where
    arbitrary = TimeOfDay
        <$> choose (0, 23)
        <*> choose (0, 59)
        <*> (fmap (MkFixed . (10^12 *)) (choose (0, 60)))
```

Then we obtain:

```
Main> sample (arbitrary :: Gen TimeOfDay)
15:00:53
14:02:44
14:44:40
12:40:12
09:55:39
10:06:02
15:00:51
15:52:23
16:59:05
22:38:45
20:23:15
```

Answer (score 2):

The reason for the bug is that `TimeOfDay`'s last constructor parameter is the number of seconds with [picosecond](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Data-Fixed.html#t:Pico) resolution.

I assume that consequently, `sec  <- elements [0 .. 60]` wasn't generating one of 61 values but one of 61 * 10¹² values.

This fixes the issue:

```
instance Arbitrary TimeOfDay where
  arbitrary = do
    hour <- elements [0 .. 23]
    min  <- elements [0 .. 59]
    -- Going till 60 accounts for leap seconds
    picoSecond <- elements [1, 2 .. 60]
    return $ TimeOfDay hour min picoSecond
```

Now, `sample (arbitrary :: Gen TimeOfDay)` produces for example:

```
17:19:03
15:49:58
01:28:40
13:20:07
12:00:01
12:35:45
13:25:33
12:55:20
07:11:54
21:10:46
14:34:15
```

---

If you also want values in the subsecond range, change the step width of the list generator:

```
picoSecond <- elements [1, 1.1 .. 60]
```

Sample values:

```
04:09:23.6
10:22:50.4
18:56:57.6
07:12:07.8
08:12:02.6
14:20:40
05:42:21.4
14:35:42.3
02:47:32.6
22:02:26.2
08:26:09.4
```

Comment: That is a *very* weird `Enum` instance. Of course, `Enum` is terminally broken, but that takes the cake.

Comment: It has no usable laws. It also involves at least two unrelated ideas mashed together.