# Haskell - Function Evaluation

Tags: haskell

I am confused about when Haskell evaluates functions, compared to when it just returns the function itself. I was taught that pattern matching drives function evaluation, but then I don't understand why

```
f :: Int -> Int
f x = x+1
```

works. Does f add 1 to an integer, or does it return a function which adds 1 to an integer? Are these two the same thing? There is no pattern matching as far as I can tell, so I'm not sure why it gets evaluated.

Another question: suppose I want to make an 8x8 list that contains all 0's, except the first row contains the numbers 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8 instead. Is there any way I could initialize it to all 0's first and then change the first row to [1..8]? I understand that it's not idiomatic to make sequential code like this, so is there a better way to do it, hopefully without using `do` blocks?

Finally, I am also confused about the `let` and `where` syntax. Suppose that in the middle of a function definition, I say `temp = x + 1`. How is this different from saying `let temp = x + 1` or `...temp where temp = x + 1`? In each of these cases, does `temp` have type `Int` or `Int -> Int`? Why do people use `do` with `let` so often?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "evaluate functions" and "return functions".

Comment: This seems like 3 completely different questions - some of them (the first, in particular) too  vaguely stated to really be able to answer. It is fine to have several different questions, but please create a new question for each, rather than putting unrelated queries into one question.

Comment: "*Suppose that in the middle of a function definition, I say `temp = x + 1`.*" That's a syntax error.

Comment: In Haskell all variables are immutable. `f` can not increment a variable. `f` simply returns a `x+1`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This certainly was a collection of questions.

Firstly, about evaluation, Haskell is lazy. It will evaluate values as they are needed. This includes the fact that a function is not necessarily evaluated in its entirety. Pattern matching may drive evaluation in some cases, for instance in [`maybe`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/src/Data.Maybe.html#maybe) either a `Nothing` or `Just x` must match, in order to find out what value is produced. But if you didn't demand the result in the first place, this matching was never needed.

`f` in your example is a function known as `(+1)`, or more explicitly `\x -> x + 1`. Being a function, it must be applied to a value to produce another, and there is in fact a pattern; the argument `x`, having type `Int`. This works as a simple binding, but it could have been a constant value pattern like `1` instead. Here's an example:

```
fib :: Int -> Int
fib 0 = 1
fib 1 = 1
fib n = fib (n-1) + fib (n-2)
```

The two first patterns give us our base cases.

An 8x8 grid of numbers is a matrix, not a list. [Data.Array](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/array-0.5.2.0/docs/Data-Array.html), [Data.Matrix](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/matrix-0.3.6.1/docs/Data-Matrix.html) and [Data.Vector](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/vector-0.12.0.3/docs/Data-Vector.html) provide types that can describe such things more accurately, and what you describe can be done. Data.Ix provides multidimensional indices and functions like [Data.Vector.modify](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/vector-0.12.0.3/docs/Data-Vector.html#v:modify) may perform updates in place without violating value immutability.

`let bindings in expression` and `expression where bindings` are mostly a matter of preference. `let binding` within a `do` block is a different matter. In your sample binding `temp = x + 1`, `x` must be bound from elsewhere, [`+`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:-43-) is of type `Num a => a -> a -> a`, so both `x` and `temp` must be the same `Num a`. A function must take an argument, so this is just a value (though mathematically it's a function of `x`).

As for `do` with `let`, it's essentially a shorthand for adding another binding; you could write:

```
main = do
    putStrLn "hello"
    let word = "world"
    putStrLn word
```

and it's equivalent to:

```
main = do
    putStrLn "hello"
    let word = "world" in do
        putStrLn word
```

This provides a way to introduce a pure value mid-`do`, like `<-` introduces monadic ones.

Comment: Please don't spread the dangerous misconception that `succ` is always the same as `(+1)` when both are available. They're different for [`Fixed`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Data-Fixed.html#t:Fixed), for example, and the assumption that they're always the same causes [real problems](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57843502/7509065).

Comment: Ah, you're right! succ would give you the next possible value while +1 would increment by one unit.